# Is there any integration code for Tabulator and asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tabulator

I am working on an Asp.net MVC (C#) project and have to use Tabulator (javascript table library) to manage data with CRUD functionality. However I cant find an example integration code which passes view Model as JSON data to tabulator script in the view for initialization. Can anybody point me in the right direction for this integration please?